# Framework JavaScript ExtJS seria a melhor opção para projetos grandes?

Tags: javascript, framework, extjs

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem experiência ou grandes conhecimentos sobre o framework JavaScript ExtJS ou algum equivalente.

O objetivo é saber se o mesmo é recomendado (recomendado = melhor opção) para sites (sites grandes, como lojas virtuais e portais, por exemplo) e também para o desenvolvimento de um sistema de tamanho médio/grande.

O objetivo é a utilização de ferramentas FREE, pois a linguagem a ser utilizada será o PHP.

--

Especificando a pergunta:

Além do AngularJS e do Jquery, onde estes estão entre os mais utilizados, gostaria de experiências sobre outras boas alternativas a se utilizar além destes. A princípio o ExtJS tinha me chamado a atenção, por isto citei ele na pergunta.

O objetivo é adquirir o conhecimento de boas alternativas seja para o desenvolvimento do sistema (back-end) como para a parte do site em si (front-end).

Agradeço pelas respostas!

Comment: Dependendo da sua aplicação a licença pode não ser gratuita. http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing/ - olhe aqui tambem; https://www.sencha.com/store/extjs/

Comment: Recomendaria o [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) para se comunicar com o PHP. Se quiser, também pode usar o [PrimeUI](http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/) para substituir os widgets do ExtJS. Se quiser, existe até uma extensão para juntar os dois o [AngularPrime](http://angularprime.appspot.com/#/main).

Comment: não existe melhor, se você quer uma interface baseada em multitelas e estilo "janelas" sim, o extjs talves poderá ser uma das opções. você citou loja virtual, é a loja em si? é o painel administrativo? o que exatamente? qualquer framework js poderá lhe auxiliar nisso.

Comment: referente a licença, o extjs pode ser utilizado em projetos opensource, assim como o @renatoargh mostrou

Comment: ah, também depende da equipe e tudo mais, as respostas abaixos, todas foram com base em opiniões.

Comment: Não conhecia. Muito interessante!!

Comment: O objetivo são de alternativas de ferramentas para o painel administrativo e para o site em sí.

Comment: Anderson, se possível leia [este artigo do nosso meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) para entender como melhorar ainda mais a pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: Meu objetivo na questão foi apenas de saber de acordo com a experiencia prática de quem vai responder qual Framework fora utilizado que se obteve sucesso, pois teorias e opiniões é o que mais se encontra na web. Caso esta não seja uma questão que esteja de acordo com o fórum, por favor me avise que irei deletar.

Comment: Oi Anderson. Não sei se é o caso de excluir a pergunta, ainda é possível editar informando as particularidades do ExtJS que te interessaram. Me parece que o principal problema é que fica difícil indicar qualquer ferramenta sem ter bem claro qual é o problema que você precisa resolver com ela. Não basta saber que se trata de um site "grande", precisaria levar em conta as particularidades dele. E no fundo é isso que a primeira frase da resposta do Edmo diz.

Comment: Meu objetivo foi a busca por opções de ferramentas (seja framework, biblioteca ou suite de componentes) em javacript através de boas experiências e não de teorias ou opiniões. Não seria um plugin ou coisa pequena para algum site em específico, como por exemplo o DHTMLX e o AngularJS seria opções já conhecidas por mim, mas estaria em busca de outras. Como não foi possível através desta, a mesma ficará da forma que está pois tentei excluir e não consegui. Agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai depender do que exatamente esse projeto (site ou lojavirtual) necessitará.

Em outras palavras frameworks como Angular, Jquery, Backbone e entre outras tem lá seus valores e falo por experiência propria de causa pois trabalho em um projeto que não é grande é gigante com arquitetura restfull e usamos apenas angular + jquery. E nos atende.

Antes de decidir seu framework veja o que realmente o ExtJS tem que você não encontrou em nenhum outro. Eu realmente não o conheço bem, mas pelo que sei para grandes projetos por organização de código, por rapidez lhe indicaria usar o AngularJS.

Até por suporte a comunidade do Angular está a cada dia mais ccom adeptos, já o ExtJS como falei eu não conheço bem.

**Pontos positivos do AngularJS:**

Possível utilização de teste no Client-side.

Binding automático. Todos as alterações feitas tanto na view quanto na model  são aplicadas automaticamente em ambas.

Template puramente declarativo. Basta que diretivas sejam adicionadas ao código HTML, isso melhor a legibilidade do template.

Ao contrário de outras APIs, não é obrigatório estender as classes do framework na definição do modelo. Isso dá mais liberdade ao desenvolvedor.

Arquitetura modular. Isso permite a criação e utilização de módulos independentes e específicos em determinadas funcionalidades.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito boa a colocação: "...veja o que realmente o ExtJS tem que você não encontrou em nenhum outro...". O angular eu já conheço, mas a ideia é esta mesmo; de alternativas ao projeto.